# javascript if else not working on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, if-statement

For some reason, the following jquery code is working in browsers but not on my iPhone:

```
        $j(".timer").each(function() {
    var htmlString = $j( this ).html();
    var stringetje = htmlString.split(';');
    var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    var timestamp = stringetje[0]-seconds;
    var numdays = Math.floor(timestamp / 86400)+" day(s) left";
    var numhours = Math.floor((timestamp % 86400) / 3600)+" hour(s) left";
    var numminutes = Math.floor(((timestamp % 86400) % 3600) / 60)+" minutes left";
// Till here everything works fine on iPhone!
    if (timestamp > 86400) { 
    jQuery("."+stringetje[2]).text(numdays); 
// alert('test'); is not showing on iPhone
     }
    if (timestamp < 86400) { 
    jQuery("."+stringetje[2]).text(numhours); 
    }
    if (timestamp < 3600) { 
    jQuery("."+stringetje[2]).text(numminutes); 
     }
    if (timestamp < 0) { 
    jQuery("."+stringetje[2]).text("Deal expired"); 
    }
```

stringetje[2] is a javascript variable and I use "." to indicate that it should target classes.

Something goes wrong in the if-statements when using variable timestamp. Does anyone have an idea why it is not working on iPhone?

PS. It is working on Android and Windows phones and all regular desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE).

Comment: done any basic debugging, e.g. doing an `alert(timestamp)` to see what value is in there on iDevices? Plus, it would appear that `stringetje` is going to be an array of strings, so you're doing `string - int`. perhaps the JS engine is puking on that.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the code I have tried putting alert(); on certain places and I found that before the if-statements everything works well. Unfortunately I cannot use the debug console of iOS as I don't have a mac to use web inspector. About your string remark, I tried using Number(timestamp) but that also doesn't work.

Comment: I tested again `alert(timestamp);` which told me "NaN". I then tested `alert(isNaN(timestamp));` which gives me "true".

Comment: so it's "not a number", which means one of your previous operations failed

Comment: Yes I think it has something to do with `var timestamp = stringetje[0]-seconds;`.

Comment: so work your way back up the chain: `alert(stringetje[0]); alert(seconds);`, etc....

Comment: Very strange, for some reason the output for `alert(htmlString);` is <a href="tel:14121421;14121421;14121421">` where a browser just shows `14121421;14121421;14121421`. Is it possible iPhone thinks it is actually a telephone number??

Comment: browser is going to render that html. do a `view source` to see what really came over from the server. You probably want `$j(this).text()` to get JUST the actual text contents.

Comment: It's not possible for me to view the source of the html on iPhone. However, in the alert it shows that apparently iPhone adds html code `<a href="tel:` before the start of `htmlString`. In short, iPhone adds code which I didn't expect which has an effect on the calculation, because iPhone recognizes it as a string and not a number.

Comment: You sir, are the hero of today. It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that iPhone apparently added html to the source, which I didn't expected. The html was changed into a clickable link as if it was a phone number e.g. `<a href="tel:14121421;14121421;14121421">` whereas browser render it as `14121421;14121421;14121421`.

To prevent this from happening, I changed this:

```
 var htmlString = $j( this ).html();
```

to this:

```
 var htmlString = $j( this ).text();
```

Credits go to Marc B (see comments).